# Spannables not coloring text in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

I'm trying to color the last 2 letters of a word, yet when I apply the span nothing happens.

Here is the code for applying the span:

```
oldWordTextView.setHighlightStatus(true);
    //Span koji uzima cijeli tekst
    String word = oldWordTextView.getText().toString();
    Log.w(word, "Rijec za animiranje highlight");
    Log.w("U animiranju prefixa", "Aniamte");
    if(word != "" && word != " "){
    final SpannableStringBuilder oldSb = new SpannableStringBuilder(word);
    final SpannableStringBuilder currentSb = new SpannableStringBuilder(buffer);

    //Span za mijenjanje boje
    final ForegroundColorSpan greenSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(60, 184, 120));//Green
    final ForegroundColorSpan redSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(251, 43, 51));//Red
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(word);

    if(isValid){
        wordToSpan.setSpan(greenSpan, word.length() - 2, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        oldSb.setSpan(greenSpan, word.length() - 2, word.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        if(buffer != "" && buffer != " ") currentSb.setSpan(greenSpan, 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        oldWordTextView.setText(wordToSpan, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        //staticTextView.setText(currentSb);
        isHighlightDone = true;
    }
    else{
        oldSb.setSpan(redSpan, 0, word.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        if(buffer != "" && buffer != " ") currentSb.setSpan(redSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        oldWordTextView.setText(oldSb);
        staticTextView.setText(currentSb);
    }
    }
```

And here is my TextView class since it's customized: http://pastebin.com/4qxL3m82

Thanks!

EDIT: I have tested and deduced that the problem lies in my custom textview class. I have tried applying the span in onDraw and onLayout methods, but the textView remains unchanged. Any ideas?

Comment: Temporarily switch back to a regular `TextView`. Does your code work? If yes, then the problem lies in your customizations to your `TextView` subclass. If not, then your problem lies in this code in this question.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and report back

Comment: Ok I have managed to color a regular textView, so I guess my problem lies in my class. Any pointers?
EDIT: I tried adding them side by side but it still isnt being shown

Comment: @CommonsWare , do you have any ideas. I believe the problem is in my setting the shaders in onDraw and onLayout which probably draw over the span.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't done custom views to the degree that you have here, so other than "you're clobbering the normal `TextView` work", I have no specific advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a SpannableString, you need to pass also the flag like this:

```
textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

I prefer personally to create utility functions to color some parts of the given String. For example, suppose you want a function for highlighting one single character and coloring the others in a different color. You could implement something like:

```
// this function colors the k-th character of String s in blue and the rest in red, and returns the SpannableString
public static SpannableString highlight(String s, int k) {
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, k, 0);
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), k, k + 1, 0);
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), k + 1, s.length(), 0);
        return ss;
    }
```

**EDIT**: well, I saw that the problem was that your method `applyLetterSpacing` was simply ignoring the old spans. So, the first solution that pops in my mind is to save the spans when calling `setText` and applying them when calling to `applyLetterSpacing`. You can see the idea here http://pastebin.com/p4Hig8Pj although as I said in my comment, the use of customized shader in `onDraw` and `onLayout` makes the coloring effect totally unexpected. Hope it helped.

Comment: I have done that already. Can you look through the pastebin I posted since I think that perhaps it is being overdrawn in onDraw or onLayout?

Comment: @mts I looked at your code, and there are two issues. The first one is that the onDraw and the onLayout overrides, although not exactly overdrawing, they can change the coloring effect. But technically speaking, the applyLetterSpacing method is the one who deletes the coloring, because you convert the original text into another one using a StringBuilder which skips the Spans created in the original SpannableString buffer. You can simply call super.setText(text, type) inside the setText override and leave out the rest to see what I mean. In any case, the result will be weird due to the shader.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to log back, I think you are right and I will accept your answer and will try it soon and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to include HTML inside your strings :

```
String str = "This word is <font color='#EE0000'>red</font>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: I need to do it dynamically and often(it's a game).

Comment: Well it all depends how many different colors you want, and if it's always on the same character/word, or if there is special processing to be done each case...

But creating a function with arguments like color/string/start point/stop point would make it easier